# Removing standard links in the posts page

Tags: posts

Is there any way of removing the 'extras' that come on the posts page? i would rather not have the links to the previous and next posts at the top and neither do I want the "This entry was posted in News. Bookmark the permalink." at the bottom.

Comment: Yes you can. Go to active template directory and edit your template files.

Comment: Thanks. If you mean from Appearance Editor - How do I know which template it is? There are many associated with Posts. You don't choose a template as you do with Pages.

Comment: I was suppose to be saying Themes. If you navigate to `Appearance` > `Editor` the current activated theme files will listed on right side.

Comment: I am looking there but I have no idea which one relates to the Posts as there are loads which are Post related. How do you know which template is being used when viewing the posts?

Comment: These data are generally controlled by the theme you are using. So the suggested way will be using the theme's options/hooks to disable them. If you are still not sure how to manage these, can I know the theme you are using?

Comment: According to @Chittaranjan What theme you're using?